# How can I have multiple types of children in a single Silverlight TreeView node?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

**Short Vesion:**

I have to display a hierarchy (`TreeView`) of items of different types, and am not sure how to do this cleanly in Silverlight. In WPF, it's straightforward to define templates (`HierarchicalDataTemplate`) based on types, but this feature isn't available in Silverlight. It seems in Silverlight you have to apply the same template to all children of a specific node, so you end up with once single monster template that handles every possible type of node, applied to every single node.

**Long Version (with example):**

To give a more concrete (but contrived) example, consider a treeview of archives in various folders, where each archive can contain photos, songs, and other archives. Each folder may contain several subfolders and archives.

```
|-Folder
  |-Folder
    |-Folder
      |-Archive
        | Photo1
        | Photo2
        | Song1
        | Song2
        |-Archive
          | Photo1
          | Song1
  |-Archive
    | Photo1
    | Photo2
    | Photo3
```

Each type in the tree (Folder, Archive, Photo, Song) is displayed differently. The obvious solution seemed to be to create a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for each type of item to display. Unfortunately, I can't find a good way to do this, because it seems that you have to specify a single template type for all of the children of a node (`ItemsSource={Binding ...}, ItemsTemplate={StaticResource TemplateForAllChildren}`).

This requirement causes the template to snowball... an archive can have Photos, Songs, and Archives as children. Because a single template must be applied to all children, that one template must be able to handle Photos, Songs, and Archives. Similarly, a Folder's template must be able to handle Folders and Archives, and the Archive template now has Photos and Songs stuck in it, so it all ends up as one giant template that can handle Photos, Songs, Archives, and Folders. As more types are added, they also get lumped into the one huge template.

Is there any way to do this cleanly, without accumulating one giant template (and associated node viewmodel) as different types are added to the tree?

Thanks!

**Some Clarification:**

Thanks for the answers so far, but I think they may just lead me back to the original issue. I may be misunderstanding the answer.

Consider the TreeView showing:

For Songs: a scrolling textbox with artist/title, and a play button

For Pictures: a thumbnail image, and a star rating control

For Archives: An archive image, with a progress bar showing the compression

For Folders: A plain label showing the folder name

As far as I can tell, the only way to achieve this is to have 1 giant HierarchicalDataTemplate containing a scrolling textbox, a play button, a thumbnail viewer, a star control, an image control, a progress bar, and a label. I'd then just selectively hide all but the one or two controls that actually apply to the node.

In WPF I could associate templates with a node type, so each node could use an appropriate template. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in Silverlight.

Thanks again!

Comment: Hm, this response has an interesting idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493551/hierarchical-templating-multiple-object-types-in-silverlight/2495070#2495070 . Although I'm not sure how to bind the template for each individual node, so that the converter is invoked for each node to select an appropriate template. I suppose this is the same problem encountered by the original poster, who replied saying he couldn't get different styles for each type of node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, why don't you try something like this?

### HierarchicalDataTemplate

```
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}" />
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FilesDataTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}" />
</sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

### Node Class

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> SubItems { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush ForegroundColor { get; set; }

    public Node(string name, Color foregroundColor, params Node[] items)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.SubItems = new ObservableCollection<Node>(items);
        this.ForegroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(foregroundColor);
    }
}
```

### Example Data

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Nodes = new Node("Root", Colors.Blue,
                             new Node("File1", Colors.Black),
                             new Node("File2", Colors.Black),
                             new Node("Archive1", Colors.Red,
                                        new Node("File3", Colors.Magenta),
                                        new Node("File4", Colors.Magenta))
                             ).SubItems;

        treeView1.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

In your case maybe could help an interface (INode for example) that has all the properties for styling nodes (like ForegroundColor, or whatever) that will be implemented by each type of subclass (Archive, Photo, Music).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I was missing some detail; I'd like to use different controls for each type. The sample you have provided would allow me to change a property's value for each node type, using the same template for every node, but I need different controls for each node type (likely requiring different templates for each node type). I have added some clarifications above. Thanks!

Comment: Well, then you could create a ContentControl that binds his content to an UIElement. For example a song will have a property called Content that could be SongControl.

Comment: Yeah.. it sounds like the only way to get this done is to actually create the UI controls in the viewmodel, instead of the view. That's what I was trying to avoid... but I guess if it's the only way, there's no much that can be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 5 we can also solve this by using the **implicit data templates**:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="treeNodeTemplate" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="ViewModels:Folder">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FolderName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="ViewModels:Song">
                    <Image Source="{Binding PictureSource}" />
                </DataTemplate>
                ...
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Roots, Mode=OneWay}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource treeNodeTemplate}"/>
```

Since Silverlight 5 still does not support automatic selection of an appropriate HierarchicalDataTemplate itself, depending on it's target type, we use the single HierarchicalDataTemplate for all types of nodes. Thus, we still need each our node view model to contain the same Children member.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this whereby I had a TreeView with multiple node types and wanted to be able to choose a different template based on the Node Type.

In the end I came across a TemplateChooser and used that in conjunction with HierarchicalDataTemplates.  (Please forgive the fact the code is in VB)

```
Public MustInherit Class TemplateSelector
    Inherits ContentControl

    Public MustOverride Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As DependencyObject) As DataTemplate

    Protected Overrides Sub OnContentChanged(oldContent As Object, newContent As Object)
        MyBase.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent)

        ContentTemplate = SelectTemplate(newContent, Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I then created a specific Template Selector for the tree view, which exposed a different Data Template based on the object type.

```
Public Class NodeTypeTemplateSelector
    Inherits TemplateSelector

    Public Property NodeType1Template As DataTemplate
    Public Property NodeType2Template As DataTemplate
    Public Property NodeType3Template As DataTemplate

    Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As System.Windows.DependencyObject) As System.Windows.DataTemplate

        If item.GetType.Equals(GetType(NodeType1VM)) Then
            Return NodeType1Template
        ElseIf item.GetType.Equals(GetType(NodeType2VM)) Then
            Return NodeType2Template
        ElseIf item.GetType.Equals(GetType(NodeType3VM)) Then
            Return NodeType3Template
        Else

            Return Nothing
        End If

    End Function
End Class
```

Here's the XAML for the HierarchicalDataTemplate I used which implements the TemplateSelector.

```
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SelectingTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding children, Mode=OneWay}">
            <local:NodeTypeTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}"
                                            NodeType1Template="{StaticResource MyNodeType1HierarchicalTemplate}"
                                            NodeType2Template="{StaticResource MyNodeType2HierarchicalTemplate}"
                                            NodeType3Template="{StaticResource MyNodeType3HierarchicalTemplate}"
                                           />
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I then of course made up some hierarchicaldatatemplates for the various types, e.g. MynodeType1HierarchicalTemplate and so on.